# Swift trailing closure stopped working when I moved the class into a Framework

Tags: swift, closures

I had a LocationManager class the performs various tasks and uses trailing closure.
Here is a method signature :

```
func getAdresseForLocation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, addressType: LocationManagerAddressType, completion: (Address?) -> Void)
```

For various reasons, I decided to move some file into a Framework, donc I declared my class and method public as follows :

```
public func getAdresseForLocation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, addressType: LocationManagerAddressType, completion: (Address?) -> Void)
```

But now I get a compilation error from the trailing closure :

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Address?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Address?) -> (Void)'
```

I tried to change the return type to (), (Void), return Void or (Void) from the closure, nothing works.
Do you have any idea what's going on?

Thakns.

Comment: What is the 'Address' declared as?

Comment: It is a struct which is declared as public too and which is in the Framework too

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
completion: ((Address)? -> Void))
```

Comment: it is not the same thing since the address returned is not mandatory in my closure. In this example, I cannot call the completion with a nil Address

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '(Address?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Address)? -> Void'

Comment: I added the ? After the (Address). Not within the ()! Try like this : ((Address)? -> ())

Comment: I know, that is what I did. Still no luck